# How to separate strings in a single column in CSV while loading into a table?

Tags: mysql

Given a CSV file of Movies with columns Movie_name and Movie_actors. There can be multiple actors for a single movie and I have to store each actor per tuple.

Say suppose the following is in CSV file having 3 columns namely Movie_name, Movie_actors, Rating (tab delimited)

```
Movie_name             Movie_actors                                                         Rating
Star Trek - 2          Chris Pine, Zachary Quinto, Zoe Saldana and Benedict Cumberbatch     7.9
```

So my resulting table after LOAD should have

```
Movie_name             Actor_name
Star Trek - 2          Chris Pine
Star Trek - 2          Zachary Quinto
Star Trek - 2          Zoe Saldana
Star Trek - 2          Benedict Cumberbatch
```

How to do this? Since the initial CSV file contains both "," & "and" separating the name of actors, how to load them into the table?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a tab-delimited file with one of its three fields being a comma-delimited string.

Comment: First: This is Start Trek 12 not 2 ... but getting serious: I cannot see a possibility for this without using some kind of script language to create the insert statements from the csv. And yes, to decide if a comma is a field separator AND a component of one field, you will have to write a little program to split up the string at the first comma, obtaining the movie title, and then splitting the rest of the string, getting your 1 .. n list of actors, not to forget the LAST separator "AND".